# Finitely generated virtually free group and its free subgroup

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, finitely-generated

Given a finitely generated virtually free group $G= \langle X \rangle$ and its free subgroup $U \subseteq G$, $U = \langle X^\prime \rangle$.

Two questions:

1. Is $U$ finitely generated?
2. Does $X^\prime \subseteq X$ hold? If not, is there an example where even $|X^\prime| > |X|$?

Comment: A subgroup of finite index in a finitely generated group is itself finitely generated, so the answer to 1 is yes if $U$ has finite index in $G$ (which you didn't say). There is no reason at all why $X' \subseteq X$ should hold, even if $U=G$. Free groups have many different generating sets. And of course you can have $|X'| > |X|$ just by adding some extra generators to $X'$.

Comment: @DerekHolt thank you, I implied $U$ to be the free subgroup of finite index in $G$. So an addition to 2: Is it possible to find a subset $X^\prime$ such that $X^\prime \subseteq X$ holds?

Comment: No not necesarily. Let $U = \langle a,b \rangle$ be free of rank two, and let $G = \langle U, c \rangle$ with $c^2=1$ and $cac=b$. Then $G = \langle a,c \rangle$ and you cannot choose $U$ as a subset of $\{ a, c \}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Summarising @DerekHolt's comments into an answer . . .*

Finitely generated subgroups are closed under finite index in finitely generated groups, which is to say that if $H$ is such that $[G:H]<\infty $ and $G$ is finitely generated, then $H$ is finitely generated too. Thus the answer to 1 is "yes".

One cannot infer that $X'\subseteq X$. If you simply add extra generators to $X'$, one can fix it so that $\lvert X'\rvert>\lvert X\rvert$ though.